# Laravel : display personal format of timestamps fields

Tags: datetime, laravel

In  my project I used this code to format timestamps fields

```
date('D m Y  H:i', strtotime($post->created_at))
```

But as I have many places and fields to display it's a bit boring, and if I need to change the format it won"t be easy to maintain.

I'd like to know if there is a way to decalre the output format

Comment: Create a variable $format = 'D m Y  H:i'; then just save the variable in a helper class, namespace and autoload the class ,then you can use helper->format

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create an accessor function in your Post model.

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    return date('D m Y H:i', strtotime($value));
}
```

This way, each time you'll call `$post->created_at` it will display the date returned by your accessor instead of the default value.

More info here : http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators

If you don't want this function in all your models your can create a BaseModel class and make your models extend this BaseModel class.

I also found an other solution:

```
\Carbon\Carbon::setToStringFormat('D m Y H:i');
```

You can use this line (in global.php for exemple) but it will change the date format in all the application.

Comment: Thnx, It's a beginning, but I'm searching for a more generic. In my I have a lot of timestamps fields n it may become long n boring to do this for every field :)

Comment: PERFECT. Thanx it"s exatly the solution I was looking for. I also redone my models before you edited your comments and now they herits from my ModelBase. Instead using the accessor you wrote i used the mutators and added =>format('xxxx'). But your new solution is perfect :)