# How can I format 'time' field - Angularjs and mySql

Tags: mysql, angularjs, laravel

I am using Laravel and Angular.  I have a function that grabs these records that include a time field (HH:MM:SS).  I only need to display the MM:SS portion of that value.

I have tried using;

```
{{ score.time | date: 'mm:ss' }}
```

but its not working.

Should I be trying to alter my table/col schema as I will never need the HH portion anyway or should I be filtering the results - either in Laravel(php) or in Angular?

**This is how I am getting the records in Laravel**

```
    public function Scores($id) {
    return Score::where('game', '=', $id)
        ->get();
}
```

Comment: in your query you can remove the HH using format.

Comment: Any chance you might provide an example?

Comment: add your laravel code that returns the results, using that I will add the answer or edit the existing I already have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be the following (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25061465/3664960))

You can create an accessor function in your Post model.

```
public function getTimeAttribute($value)
{
    return date('i:s', strtotime($value));
}
```

This way, each time you'll call $score->time it will display the date returned by your accessor instead of the default value.

More info here : [accessors-and-mutators](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators)

If you don't want this function in all your models your can create a BaseModel class and make your models extend this BaseModel class.

Comment: Makes sense.  Now if I want to do this in my php or more likely in my angular, can I just try to format the returned results?

Comment: the results are already formatted if you use this in the query. No need for an extra formatting in php or angular.

Comment: Sorry, I need to be clearer.  I am currently pulling the records via php (Laravel) like so;

        public function Scores($id) {
        return Score::where('game', '=', $id)
            ->get();
    }

Comment: This changes the question entirely! Update your question to explain this also, try not to leave essential information anymore as the answer will resemble your question!

Comment: I have edited the question.  You're correct sorry.  I am tired!

Comment: check out the last part (under the horizontal line)

Comment: Yes, an accessor makes sense.  I have applied that to my Model but no luck.  The col is time not date, but changing 'date' to 'time' in the accessor has no impact.

Comment: Also, changing the field to datetime had no impact.  When I dd the results its the full value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101789/discussion-between-davejal-and-tenz).

Comment: removed the top part as it didn't resemble an answer to the question it became